# SQL Query not returning proper records

Tags: sql, radgrid

I have 3 Tables from which I have to fetch records together, and have to display in a RadGrid.

From Table-1 say **Request** table, I have to fetch below columns:

R.RequestID
R.BarcodeNo
R.Company
R.Status

from Table-2 say **Xml** table, I have to fetch below columns:

x.ScannedBy
x.ScannedDate
x.VerifiedBy
x.VerifiedDate

from Table-3 say **Workflow** table, I have to fetch below columns:

W.Action
W.UserName
W.CreatedDate

Now, this `W.Action` column has following data, in a **Workflow** table:
[image]

This `W.Action` column can have repeated data as I have shown above.
And for every "*Action*" Column , there is "*UserName*" column and "*CreatedDate*" column in **Workflow** table.

Now, I have to fetch the records from above 3 tables whose `W.Action = 'Submit'`
and `W.Action = 'Update'`
And also, in Select query, I have to Select `W.Action = 'Submit'` as a different column and `W.Action = 'Update'` as a different column, as below format:
[image]

For this, I created below query:

```
Select * FROM
(
SELECT distinct

R.RequestID,
R.BarcodeNo,
R.Company,
R.Status,

x.ScannedBy,
x.ScannedDate,
x.VerifiedBy,
x.VerifiedDate,

W.Action, W.UserName as SubmitName, W.CreatedDate as SubmitDate

From [tbl_Request] (NOLOCK) R
Left Join [tbl_Xml](NOLOCK) X On X.XmlID = R.XmlID
Left Join [tbl_Workflow] (NOLOCK) W On W.RequestID = R.RequestID

Where W.Action = 'Submit'
) as A

Left Join

(
SELECT RequestID, W.Action, W.UserName as UpdateName , W.CreatedDate AS UpdateDate

From [tbl_Request] (NOLOCK) R
Left Join [tbl_Xml](NOLOCK) X On X.XmlID = R.XmlID
Left Join [tbl_Workflow] (NOLOCK) W On W.RequestID = R.RequestID

Where Action = 'Update'
) as B 

ON A.RequestID=B.RequestID
```

Through above query I can successfully get the `Action = 'Submit'` as 
a separate column and `Action = 'Update'` as a separate column'

> But I am not getting the proper records.

If I run the 1st part of query alone (i.e., for Action = 'Submit')
it gives me 142747 records
AND If I run 2nd part of query alone (i.e., for Action = 'Update')
it gives me 73021 records
BUT If I run whole query at once, it gives me only 215774 records, which is not proper. 
**It is suppose to give me (142747 + 73021) records.**

Please let me know what is wrong in my query ?
How to get the proper records along with Action = Submit & Action = Update as a separate columns.
Please reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   SELECT 

    R.RequestID,
    R.BarcodeNo,
    R.Company,
    R.Status,

    x.ScannedBy,
    x.ScannedDate,
    x.VerifiedBy,
    x.VerifiedDate,

    max(case when W.Action='Submit' then W.UserName end) as SubmitName, 
    max(case when W.Action='Submit' then W.CreatedDate end) as SubmitDate, 
    max(case when W.Action='Update' then W.UserName end) as UpdateName  ,
    max(case when W.Action='Update' then W.CreatedDate end) as UpdateDate

    From [tbl_Request] (NOLOCK) R
    Left Join [tbl_Xml](NOLOCK) X On X.XmlID = R.XmlID
    Left Join [tbl_Workflow] (NOLOCK) W On W.RequestID = R.RequestID

    Where W.Action in ( 'Submit','Update')
group by 
  R.RequestID,
    R.BarcodeNo,
    R.Company,
    R.Status,

    x.ScannedBy,
    x.ScannedDate,
    x.VerifiedBy,
    x.VerifiedDate
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Your code is working fine but when it separate the **Action** column for 'Submit' & 'Update' i.e, SubmitName SubmitDate UpdateName UpdateDate, it display the `SubmitName SubmitDate` as one row for ID=101 and it display `UpdateName UpdateDate` as other row for ID=101. i.e., Im getin 2 rows for same ID. **Requirement is:** for a particular ID, if I am getting Action='Submit' and 'Update' both, then after separation thr data should display in 1 row, not in 2 different rows. Please let me know how to achieve it. Please reply

Comment: It's easy. I've hidden action column, added group by and add max() to columns for name and date

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Issue is still the same using `group by`.

Comment: @user3196511 Again 2 rows? Can you check data for this rows in columns, that defined in group by? It should be difference in them.

Comment: Yes again for same ID I am getting 2 rows. For Action=Submit data is coming in 1 row leaving Update column as Null, and for Action=Update data is coming in another column, leaving Submit column as NULL

Comment: @user3196511 Have you copied my new query, which I've edited half an hour ago? I've removed column [Action] from select and from group by. You shouldn't select this column, if you need only one row

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But When I remove Action column from `Select` or `Where` clause I get this error: `Column '[tbl_Workflow].Action' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`